# Can block layer receive commands with same LBA at a time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

1.
    I don't see this happening for requests from the same thread. Is this true? if not, can you please provide scenarios for this to occur? This could happen with applications using DIRECT flag, but not with applications using the page cache ? 
If one application uses the DIRECT flag and another uses the ASYNC mode, how will this work.

2.
    If we have different threads that cause this conflict(of LBA- two writes, or 1Read,1Write) to occur, who will resolve this conflict ? Whom does this fall on ?

3.
    Is there some kind of ordering that needs to be maintained?

Per my understanding, the block layer can rearrange "requests" in the scheduler . So unless there is a barrier request, there should be no ordering enforced between commands